# Can't run Cassandra on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, cassandra

I have installed Cassandra on ubuntu 12.04 .

But when I start it, the following error occurrs:

`cassandra -f
xss =  -ea -javaagent:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/jamm-0.2.5.jar -XX:+UseThreadPriorities -XX:ThreadPriorityPolicy=42 -Xms1493M -Xmx1493M -Xmn373M -Xss160k
Segmentation fault (core dumped)`

I did the following to solve it but nothing happens:
in `/etc/conf/cassandra-env.sh` I commented the following lines:

```
JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError"

# set jvm HeapDumpPath with CASSANDRA_HEAPDUMP_DIR
if [ "x$CASSANDRA_HEAPDUMP_DIR" != "x" ]; then
    JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -XX:HeapDumpPath=$CASSANDRA_HEAPDUMP_DIR/cassandra-`date +%s`-pid$$.hprof"
fi
```

and ran the following commands on shell as root:

`unset IBM_HEAPDUMP

unset  IBM_HEAP_DUMP`

How should I solve it?

Comment: If your code-block contains backticks, it may screw up the display. You can use four spaces at the beginning of each code line to mark as code, as well, preserving the backticks inside the code.

Comment: Why do you think that IBM-specific env variables are relevant to why the jvm is crashing under cassandra? You appear to have hit a JVM bug.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had same problem, and found the following:

```
$ cassandra -f
xss =  -ea -javaagent:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/jamm-0.2.5.jar -XX:+UseThreadPriorities -XX:ThreadPriorityPolicy=42 -Xms826M -Xmx826M -Xmn100M -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Xss180k
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

ok, how about:

```
$ sudo cassandra -f
xss =  -ea -javaagent:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/jamm-0.2.5.jar -XX:+UseThreadPriorities -XX:ThreadPriorityPolicy=42 -Xms826M -Xmx826M -Xmn100M -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Xss180k
```

..no Segmentation Fault this time, and maybe the 'xss' part is just an obscure debugging message in that case?

```
$ ps -Af | grep cass
ubuntu    5687   959  0 15:42 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto cass
```

hmm, no processes started though.

What did work for me is:

```
$ sudo /etc/init.d/cassandra start
xss =  -ea -javaagent:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/jamm-0.2.5.jar -XX:+UseThreadPriorities -XX:ThreadPriorityPolicy=42 -Xms826M -Xmx826M -Xmn100M -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Xss180k
$ ps -Af | grep cass
root      5789     1  0 15:45 ?        00:00:00 jsvc.exec -user cassandra -home [blah blah blah] org.apache.cassandra.thrift.CassandraDaemon
106       5791  5789 13 15:45 ?        00:00:06 jsvc.exec -user cassandra -home [blah blah blah] org.apache.cassandra.thrift.CassandraDaemon
```

...though I realise that's not running it in the foreground like `cassandra -f` is supposed to.

I eventually gave up and started over, avoiding manual installation by just booting an EC2 instance from the DataStax Community AMI: https://aws.amazon.com/amis/datastax-auto-clustering-ami-2-2

But... I just found what looks like the real answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12941854/202168

Answer (score 1):

See my answer here, https://stackoverflow.com/a/14447535/92463 which describes increasing the stack segment size to enable Cassandra on OpenJDK.