# Cassandra error "Could not create the Java Virtual Machine"

Tags: cassandra

I'm new to Cassandra. Followed this link http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/2.0/webhelp/index.html#cassandra/install/installDeb_t.html to install Cassandra in Ubuntu virtual box of 1GB RAM.

Output of `cassandra -f`:

```
xss =  -ea -javaagent:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/jamm-0.2.5.jar -XX:+UseThreadPriorities -XX:ThreadPriorityPolicy=42 -Xms501M -Xmx501M -Xmn100M -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Xss256k
Unrecognized VM option 'UseCondCardMark'
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

Here, it shows `out of memory` error and it would be reason for not creating JVM.
Can you please help on resolving this issue.

Thanks for any help.

cassandra-env.sh file:

```
# Per-thread stack size.
JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Xss1500k"

echo "xss = $JVM_OPTS"
```

Comment: Tried this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16831724/error-when-starting-cassandra-prevents-launching. Increased stack size to -Xss1500k!. Still not working.

Comment: can you copy your cassandra-env.sh here? especially the JVM_OPTS part

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove

```
if [ "$JVM_VERSION" \> "1.7" ] ; then
    JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -XX:+UseCondCardMark"
fi
```

from your cassandra-env.sh.

Comment: check this link :) https://blogs.oracle.com/dave/entry/false_sharing_induced_by_card

Comment: complicated :) Thanks anyway.

Answer (score -3):

Maybe your java version should be 1.8