# Error while starting Cassandra Server

Tags: cassandra, nosql

Starting Cassandra Server
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for 2097152KB object heap
Screenshot :
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: check your storage capacity,maybe you haven't enough storage space

Comment: I am having 1gb of RAM free, is it fine?

Comment: how much storage is free in your disk?

Comment: Free RAM 1GB
Free Space in Disk = 25GB

Comment: Check this Ritesh https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16831724/error-when-starting-cassandra-prevents-launching